# How do different virtual machines handle CPU scheduling?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, hyper-v, parallels, xen

When you give a guest OS multiple virtual CPUs (vCPU), the virtual machine has to assign them to physical CPUs (pCPU). I can't find any info on how most VMs handle this. There are 2 broad categories: strict co-scheduling (also called gang scheduling), and relaxed co-scheduling. I'm pretty sure VMware ESXi and MS Hyper-V use relaxed.

Does anyone know about any others?

1. VMware Workstation or Fusion
2. Parallels Desktop
3. Xen
4. VirtualBox
5. KVM

and any others that I may have missed...